# Foundation 6 Reveal Modal forcing page to #top

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

I inherited this site (http://www.fatimatourforpeace.com/wordpress/the-tour) from a former coworker and I've solved most of the small problems with the site, but this one.

The modals on the page (click More Information) force the page back up to the top, instead of showing the modal in the area the user is currently in.

I thought it was something with assigning 100% height to the html/body tags or a couple of other things, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Yes. I added position:fixed on .reveal and that seems to have "fixed" the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I added position:fixed on .reveal and that seems to have "fixed" the issue for this site.